# Question Style Guidlines

Tags: discussion

Another [post](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-am-i-being-downvoted-for-this-question) brought this question to mind: what should we do vs. what can be done to ensure high quality questions? Not in terms of content, but in terms using Salesforce nomenclature, complete sentences, etc.

I'm not saying this should be a grammar-Nazi kind of situation, but could we collaborate on a **Manual of Style** kind of reference to link to when needed?

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to have defined guidelines somewhere, but you can't always expect everybody to adhere to them, especially for those whose native language is not English. That said, everybody can earn the power to edit questions, so if those of us who do actively edit have a set of guidelines to work from it may aid consistency across the site.

Sounds to me like this might be a great feature for the FAQ.

Comment: Let me start: I insist our process documents at $job use capitals for object names and lowers for the general noun. Eg. "Please make sure you log every phone call as Activity on an Opportunity"