# Downvoting in general

Tags: discussion, downvoting

I've just noticed [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/540/apex-repeat-using-set-collection) currently has a score of -1.  I'm not sure why, but as an beta site we need to be wary of downvote trends.

The question isn't mine, but I'm concerned. The question seems to make sense and seems to have good answers (though one is in the comments .. !)

We need to answer: **What is our downvoting policy?**

Am I wrong in thinking the question shouldn't have been downvoted? Has it just been downvoted because someone thought it's a n00b question?

Answer (score 4):

Downvotes are very essential for an Q&A sites, just to keep away very vague and broad questions. We should leave those to discussion forums and not Q&A sites.

Here the questions have to be clear with code if necessary and need to show key research efforts.

We need to make sure that downvotes are used carefully. We need let the person who raised the question know that this question is not right and ask him to make changes (use comments) and if the user does not update the question then downvote.

Also take a look at the answer by Anup for a [related question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-am-i-being-downvoted-for-this-question?rq=1) on downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't cast the down vote, I do agree with Prady.

If, for example, the question hadn't been answered yet, people asked for clarification and still the questioner declined to clarify by including relevant code or clearly explaining the details of what they are doing, then a down vote is a perfect indicator that the quality of question is lacking - at least in the eyes of the one casting the down vote.