# Criteria for downvoting

Tags: discussion, downvoting

Why did this que  get downvoted twice ?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/rest-api-web-application-not-working

I thought the question had enough details. 
Even looking at the answers from this link, the user has done his/ her own research before the question was posted. 
 [Downvoting in general](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/downvoting-in-general)

Is there something I am missing. I was following the thread and got surprised to see down votes. I might have obviously missed something about down vote policies

Comment: the fact that there are no answers and a long list of comments with questions would indicate that the user didn't really post enough details or do any reasearch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I have two ideas:

1. The question is about setting up a non-Salesforce application for testing a REST API. While based on a Salesforce tutorial, the question is about the non-SF component.
2. It's hard to troubleshoot the app setup. It is running in Apache, but Apache has a lot of configuration options and this isn't really the best forum for helping configure Apache installs.